# In the question below, I do not see why $P(X=1)=P(X=5)=P(Y=2)=P(Y=4)=\frac12$

Tags: probability

[image]

This question is from my Actuarial Exam P study guide, and there is something seemingly simple that I am not seeing.

The solution states that 4$\theta_{1}+6\theta_{2}=1$
This makes sense.

Then they say
P(X=1)=P(X=5)=P(Y=4)=P(Y=2)=2$\theta_{1}$+3$\theta_{2}$=1/2
Where did the 1/2 come from?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, if $4\theta_1+6\theta_2=1$ then...

Answer (score 1):

The joint distribution has been set up so that all row sums and all column sums are equal to $2\theta_1+3\theta_2$. Since the sum of the row sums must be $1$ by probability axioms, the row sums must equally divide this value, so each row has probability $\frac12$. The same reasoning applies for column sums.